# Partially completed circle (with text) in CSS

Tags: css, text, numbers, geometry

I'm trying to create the following effect with on a design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhima.png

I can create a bordered circle fine - but the matter of partially completing the circle is proving difficult. There are a myriad of different ways to do this with Javascript and Canvas, but I can't find a solid way to achieve it in CSS. I don't mind having a number of different classes for different values, but is there an elegant solution available?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? Circliful jQuery Plugin https://longren.io/circliful-a-jquery-plugin-providing-animated-progress-circles/

Comment: Yeah, ideally CSS only. It's possible that I might end up having to go with Javascript, but it's one of those things I think must be possible in pure CSS surely?

Comment: It isn't possible to do with pure CSS. How do you want to apply different numbers? Which browsers do you want to support?

Comment: It's definitely possible, I've seen it in codepens - but they look incredible complex. I was more wondering if there's an elegant solution that makes changing the amount easier. So far it looks like Javascript is the easier solution though.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**: this is very possible using pure CSS3.

*(You should be able to open the below demo and customize to your result)*

Use `@keyframes` to [animate](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) between the numbers. You'll need to add this.

Below is using `@keyframes 'rotate' {` for the circular motion.

```css
body { background: #222; }

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 92%;
  height: 92%;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  
}

.spinner {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right: 50px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;

  -webkit-animation: rotate 1.6s infinite;

          animation: rotate 1.6s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes 'rotate' {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes 'rotate' {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
            transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't exactly what I was aiming for but it might be able to be repurposed. It looks good. I was instead just aiming for a static circle - which would be full at 10 and empty at 0.0 - 5.0 would be half full for example. Your code is useful, though.

Comment: Ah, I see. You could still achieve that with this method here. It would just be a lot more @keyframes animations embeded between the rotate. I'll see if I'm able to come back with some more complete code, but I'm 100% you dont need any JS for this ;)

Comment: Just to confirm, I don't think I would be needing keyframes as I'd like the circle to be static. It's just a "score" that would be visualised by a partially complete circle - animation isn't really needed at all.